# How can I get whether textBox is changed in Android Activity?

Tags: android

I have a activity contains many edittexts. How can I know whether the user have input or change the content of the edittext?

Not check one edittext, there are many edittexts in the activity. If one of them has been changed. While the user leave the activity, I need tell he/her, the information is not saved.

Comment: `addTextChangedListener` . Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: textboxes in this case refers to textview or editext?

Comment: Not check one edittext, there are many edittexts in the activity. If one of them has been changed. While the user leave the activity, I need tell he/her, the information is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume textboxes in this case refers to editext

Use a text watcher as below

```
EditText search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  // s is typed text       
}

 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
           int after) {
 }

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
});
```

If its textview check the link below

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)